# Restore SQL server logins from DB files of not-running sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Our admin has backed-up (in Veeam) a windows server with SQL server (v 2016) installed on it.

Then he uninstalled the SQL server and installed a newer version - 2019.
Then he tried to restore the backup on another machine, but unsuccessfully. He has submitted a support ticket.
[The official manual - *Transfer logins and passwords...*][1] requires the original SQL's instance to be running, but is there another way to recover (the original) SQL server's logins and roles (even SQL jobs) from mdf's (we have them available) while we are waiting for a support from Veeam?

We have a little time left...
Thanks for any help

```
  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restore the old [master] database files as:-

```
master_recover.mdf
master_recover.ldf
```

Attach the files as a new database called [master_recover]:-

```
CREATE DATABASE [master_recover] ON 
( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master_recover.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master_recover.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Open a query window using DAC ([DAC from SSSMS](https://mssqltrek.com/2018/06/28/dedicated-admin-connectiondac-from-ssms/)):-

`ADMIN:.` (local un-named Instance)

Query the old Login data using three-part-naming to access the recovered base table:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM [master_recover].[sys].sysxlgns;
```

Create new Logins based on the recovered data.

Server Role membership can similarly be extracted by querying the recovered base table:-

```
SELECT ROLES.[name] AS ServerRoleName,
       MEMBERS.[name] AS LoginName
FROM [master_recover].[sys].sysmultiobjrefs AS SRM
    INNER JOIN [master_recover].[sys].sysxlgns AS ROLES
        ON ROLES.id = SRM.indepid
    INNER JOIN [master_recover].[sys].sysxlgns AS MEMBERS
        ON MEMBERS.id = SRM.depid
WHERE SRM.class = 26
      AND SRM.depsubid = 0
      AND SRM.indepsubid = 0
      AND MEMBERS.[sid] NOT IN ( 0x1 )
ORDER BY ROLES.[name],
         MEMBERS.[name];
```

These base tables and queries can be found by looking at the definition of the system views `sys.server_principals` and `sys.server_role_members`.

Comment: perfect, thanks, When I create the logins based on the sysxlgns could I transfer the server-roles membership to them, kind of like [this here: Transfer logins and passwords...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances) ? Thank you

Comment: @myro I've edited the query in the answer to return ServerRoleName and LoginName,

Comment: awesome, thank you very much sir!